# Regular expression get last characters

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression which will take the characters from the last "slash" "/" to the right.

Exemple1 : http:// thesite.com/tester/blabla/this_is_the.jpg - I want to extract only the "this_is_the.jpg"
Exemple2 : http:// thesite.com/tester/blabla/this_is_2.jpg - Only the "this_is_2.jpg"

Comment: Try `\/(.+?)$`. Group 1 will contain what you want.

Comment: @AmalMurali `\/([^/]+)$` is "safer" :)

Comment: Why are you escaping the slash ?

Comment: @Amine: In some languages, the regex requires to be wrapped in delimiters. `/` is the most commonly used delimiter — if the delimiter is a `/`, all occurrences of `/` must be escaped inside the pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
[^/]+$
```

Which basically says: "give me all characters at the end that are not slashes".

Example:

```
$ echo 'http:// thesite.com/tester/blabla/this_is_the.jpg' | egrep -o '[^/]+$'
this_is_the.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

short answer:

```
/[^\/]*$/
```

explaination

`$` match end of the string
   `[^\/]` any character except `/`
   `*` any number of things matched by previous token

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using sed:

```
sed 's#.*/\([^/]*\)$#\1#'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would anchor it on the extension, personally - then your validating that all in one go.

```
"/bla bala/this_is_the.jpg" 

\/([^\/]+\.jpg)$ 
Array
(
    [0] => /this_is_the.jpg
    [1] => this_is_the.jpg
)
```

for other file types

```
\/([^\/]+\.(jpg|png|bmp))$

Array
(
    [0] => /this_is_the.jpg
    [1] => this_is_the.jpg
    [2] => jpg
)
```

for the other guys ( cant comment yet ) I would avoid the * and go with +, do you really want it to match on this "/bla bala/this_is_the/" ~ no file